# Linear Independence of Matrix Product

Tags: linear-algebra

If the columns of $X$ are a basis for the range of a matrix $B$, and $V$ is a basis for $\ker(AX)$, then show that $XV$ is linearly independent.

I know that $AXV=0$. How can I use this to show that $XV$ is linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, what you need is that $X$ sends linearly independent vectors to linearly independent vectors. In fact $V$ being a basis implies that $V$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, and you want this set to be sent to a linearly independent set by $X$.

The columns of $X$ are a basis, hence $X$ can be viewed as a matrix of base change, that eats the coordinates of some vectors, written in a basis $\mathcal{B}$ and sends them to the coordinates of the same vectors in a base $\mathcal{B}'$ (every invertible matrix can be viewed as a base change matrix). Now, two vectors are linearly independent independently of the basis in which we write their coordinates, hence $X$ (it's just a change of basis) preserves linear independence.